# Find element in a list with a substring

Tags: python, arrays, find, element

I have a pickle file which contains the following data stored:

```
indices = np.load("descritores/indices_pessoa.pickle")
print(indices) # result

 {0: 'fotos\\pessoa.1.1.jpg', 1: 'fotos\\pessoa.1.2.jpg', 2: 'fotos\\pessoa.1.3.jpg', 3: 'fotos\\pessoa.2.1.jpg', 4: 'fotos\\pessoa.2.2.jpg', 5: 'fotos\\pessoa.2.3.jpg'}
```

I would like to get all indexes of elements which contains "pessoa.1" as substring, and remove them from the list.

I've tried this so far, but not working:

```
r = [i for i in indices if "pessoa.1" in i]
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an output from you question I see dictionary.

> {0: 'fotos\pessoa.1.1.jpg', 1: 'fotos\pessoa.1.2.jpg', 2: 'fotos\pessoa.1.3.jpg', 3: 'fotos\pessoa.2.1.jpg', 4: 'fotos\pessoa.2.2.jpg', 5: 'fotos\pessoa.2.3.jpg'}

If you understand "index" as a key from dictionary, just iterate it.

```
indexes = []
for index, value in indices.items():
    if 'pessoa.1' in value:
        indexes.append(index)
for index in indexes:
    del indices[index]
```